# Spring custom authentication manager (with custom user details service)

Tags: spring-security

In my Spring app, I want my ProviderManager class to implement Serializable class (for my own reason), of course we can't edit Spring code, so one way that I did is to use a custom class called CustomProviderManager that extends ProviderManager and implements Serializable class.
My old declaration of authentication manager likes this:

```
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService" >
        <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
      </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

How can I config likes above snippet for my CustomProviderManager class (my authentication provider of my custom authentication manager should use custom user details service name "**customUserDetailsService**" and password encoder is "**md5**")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends a little bit on your CustomProviderManager, but something like this:

```xml
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="CustomProviderManager">
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
      <property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService"/>
      <property name="passwordEncoder">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"/>
      </property>
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Although it's a little bit late, but thank for your solution :)